# Migrating a Yii site to Craft

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I have a large site running Yii (1.1.x), complete with many controllers for specific applications.

A big section of the site is "static" pages, which use Yii to render out using a site layout.

I'm interested in migrating the "static" portions of the site into content management, but I need to keep my applications. Is there an easy way to create Craft plugins that will call my existing Yii controllers? Or is there some other way to port the functionality without rewriting everything?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to create Craft plugins that will call my existing Yii controllers?

There might be a way, but I'm not sure how easy it'd be.

I think it'd be a more guaranteed easy path if you were to take your existing Yii controllers and turn them into Craft plugin [controllers](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers), but I'm not sure of the extent and complexity of your existing application.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is going to be an easy one-to-one mapping for migrating a Yii site to Craft. There may be several areas you can reuse code, but I expect you'll need to restructure things a bit to fit the Craft plugin architecture.

You also mention a handful of static pages. It sounds like these pages are not pulling from a database already but that you will want to migrate them into Craft.  For these, you'll likely need to migrate things into the Craft database and then update your existing code to be integrated with this data.

It's hard to be too specific without understanding more about how your current data is stored and what types of specific applications you'd need to be porting over.